# @NamedNativeQuery multiple resultsets

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Is it possible to get back multiple resultsets with @NamedNativeQuery+Spring+Hibernate?

I am using `HibernateTemplate.findByNamedQuery` to lookup a DAO object mapped like so:

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQueries( {
    @NamedNativeQuery( callable = true, name = "QueryName", query = "pStoredProcedureName ?, ?, ?", readOnly = true,
        resultClass = DAOClass.class ),
```

But now the stored procedure I am calling has multiple result sets and I can only seem to get the first one.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate: Multiple Result Sets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831672/hibernate-multiple-result-sets)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Core_Reference_Guide/sp_query.html) I don't think it is possible.

> For Sybase or MS SQL server the following rules apply:
>
> The procedure must return a result set. Note that since these servers
>   can return multiple result sets and update counts, Hibernate will
>   iterate the results and take the first result that is a result set as
>   its return value. Everything else will be discarded.